# This expression is not callable. Type 'Number' has no call signatures

Tags: node.js, typescript, model

Hi I'm new in Typescript, I have an object-type variable in which might be different values from different types or nested object. now my question is that how can I define a model for this object to don't face the example error when call different keys?

For example:

```
export class Controller {
protected static response(res: Response, statusCode: number = 200, data: any, user: string = '', dev: string = '', code: number = 200, result: string = 'success'){
    res.status(statusCode).send({
        data: data,
        message: {
            user: '',
            dev: ''
        },
        code: 403,
        result: 'Error'
    })
}


 ERROR: res.status ---> This expression is not callable. Type 'Number' has no call signatures
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I was getting this error as well, and realized I'd just forgotten to import Response. Adding an import line solved the problem for me.

```
import express, {Request, Response} from 'express';
```

Comment: For context. What happens is by default typescript imports it automatically from the core of HTTP node library. And the `status` under the `Response` object there is a `Number`.

Comment: it's ridiculous.. my times..

Answer (score 16):

In NextJS make sure you import the correct Response type.

```js
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";
```

Comment: thank you, I was importing the wrong type

Answer (score 4):

In your contoller just import the response from `express` or the framework that you use and it will work.

```js
import { Response } from 'express';
```

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps anyone else, I have also seen the same error in cases like this:

```js
const shift = progressWidth * percentage
(this.$refs.expected as Vue).$el.style.left = "100px"
```

Where `percentage` is a `number`. The error occurs because without semicolons the second line is being interpreted as part of the line, like this:

```js
const shift = progressWidth * percentage(this.$refs.expected as Vue).$el.style.left = "100px"
```

This can be fixed by adding a leading semi-colon:

```js
const shift = progressWidth * percentage
;(this.$refs.expected as Vue).$el.style.left = "100px"
```

Or even better, rearrange so it isn't needed at all:

```js
const expected = (this.$refs.expected as Vue).$el
const shift = progressWidth * percentage
expected.$el.style.left = "100px"
```

Answer (score 2):

`res.status` is a number according to that error message. It doesn't look like that Controller is being called with the correct arguments. `console.log(res)` in there before calling `res.status` and check your call site code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line first to get to get all the functionality of express in NEXTJS. REMEMBER you added this exact lines, not others which are mention in this page.

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"; 

// This function handle the POST request and defeat all your errors.
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

// You must have to mention the type of handle function's parameter which we already
//get from next package (NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse). 
//NOTE:- You can change the function name, that's your choice

export default function handle(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method !== "POST") {
        res.status(405)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use
`(res as any).status(statusCode).send({data: data, message:{user: '',dev: ''},code: 403,result: 'Error'})`
for any typescript libraries/framework if you use like express, nestjs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).